# Is there a difference between "in Christ" and "in Jesus"?

Tags: christology

If I do a search on the relative frequencies of "in Christ," "in Christ Jesus," "in Jesus Christ," and "in Jesus," the vast majority are written as "in Christ" or "in Christ Jesus."  Is there a reason theologically between "Christ Jesus" and "Jesus Christ" and why would we be "in" one and not the other?

Examples:

Rom 3:24 
"and are justified by his grace as a gift, through the redemption that is **in Christ Jesus**"

Rom 9:1 
"I am speaking the truth **in Christ**—I am not lying; my conscience bears me witness in the Holy Spirit"

Rom 3:22
"the righteousness of God through faith **in Jesus Christ** for all who believe."

Rom 3:26
"It was to show his righteousness at the present time, so that he might be just and the justifier of the one who has faith **in Jesus**."

ESV:

- "in Christ Jesus" (50 occurrences)
- "in Christ" (37 occurrences)
- "in Jesus Christ" (3 occurrences)
- "in Jesus" (6 occurrences)

NIV

- "in Christ Jesus" (47 occurrences)
- "in Christ" (38 occurrences)
- "in Jesus Christ" (3 occurrences)
- "in Jesus" (7 occurrences)

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! I like this question, but for the site we'd like to see it expanded. Can you [edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/28439/edit) into it an example verse of each phrase and maybe the number of hits you found for each?

Comment: I updated my original post.

Comment: The answer could be different per author and work, and even in each context. This is too broad. Also, you specifically are looking for a *theological* reason, which is not clear and too broad.

Comment: @Dan Of course the answer _could_ differ per author and work (and also translation) but in that case pointing out a few notable differences would make a decent answer. I don't tend to thing this is too broad because it's explicitly about a specific pattern and whether the pattern is meaningful. Where the differences and what boundaries they cross basically _is_ the question. If you tried to narrow this down to one instance you'd loose the gist of what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

In the texts you quote, there is no distinction between "Jesus Christ" and "Christ Jesus."  Initially, "Christ" was considered a title.  It was the Greek equivalent of the Hebrew word Messiah, which means "the Anointed One."  *Christos* is the Greek, and *Mashiach* is the Hebrew.  In ancient Israel, kings and high priests were appointed to office by being anointed with oil.  The Messiah would be God's ideal Anointed One.

*Jesus* is a personal name (*Yeshuah* in Hebrew).  So "Jesus Christ" means "Jesus the Messiah," and "Christ Jesus" means "the Messiah Jesus."  In Rom. 3:24 and 9:1 the simple preposition *en* ("in") is used, referring to "the redemption that is in Christ Jesus" and "the truth in Christ."  These are ways of expressing redemption in the Messiah Jesus and the truth in the Messiah.  They refer to the same person.

Rom. 3:22 and 3:26 have no preposition in the Greek, but instead are in the genitive case which indicates possession, and may be literally translated "of Jesus Christ" and "of Jesus".  There has been much discussion as to whether this involves our own faith *in* Jesus or the faith *of* Jesus himself.  Is it our faith or Jesus' faith?  Grammarians refer to this as the subjective genitive as opposed to the objective genitive.

You did not quote any texts which refer to *believers* as being in Christ, such as Gal. 3:28; 2 Cor. 12:2.  With regard to this 'being in Christ,' the emphasis is upon "Christ" because believers are taken into the body of Christ and thereby share his anointing in the Holy Spirit. (2 Cor. 1:21; 1 Cor. 12:12, 27)